# Name of the lubuntu screen brightness programme

Tags: lubuntu, brightness, mac, i3-wm

I have lubuntu 13.04 on a couple of year old iMac and using the screen brightness keyboard buttons works great out of the box. However, I tend to use i3wm as my primary windows manager and the buttons don't work there. I can use a workaround using xrandr to adjust the gamma (rather than actual brightness), but it would seem easier to just call whatever programme lxde uses within i3wm.

Does anyone know the name of the programme and/or how to find such a thing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xfce4-power-manager if it's not working out of the box. In 13.10 I haven't used any power manager but brightness is working now. Must be something included in kernel or X updates.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find it because I was looking for something with lx in its name.